# Start notebook from other notebook

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

Using jupyter-lab

```
%run otherNotebook.ipynb
```

gives the following error message

> Error: file not found otherNotebook.ipynb.py

How can I use the magic method and prevent it from adding `.py` to the file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) `%run` is for running a named file inside IPython as a program. Jupyter notebooks are not Python programs.

Notebooks can be converted to Python programs/scripts using [Jupytext](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext#command-line-conversion). Following that conversion you could then use `%run`.

Alternatively, you can use [nbconvert to execute a notebook](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html) or use [Papermill to execute a notebook](https://github.com/nteract/papermill#executing-a-notebook). Papermill allows you to easily pass in parameters at the time of run. I have an example of both commented out in code under 'Step #5' [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/fomightez/rcomptest-accompmatz/blob/master/notebooks/2-MakeNbs.ipynb#STEP-#5:-Start-it-cycling-through-markdown-files-making-the-output-notebooks-(unrun)) and 'Step#2' [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/fomightez/rcomptest-accompmatz/blob/master/notebooks/3-Run.ipynb#STEP-#2:-Run-each-notebook.).

If you are actually trying to bring the code into your present notebook, then you may want to explore [importing Jupyter notebooks as modules](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html). [importnb](https://pypi.org/project/importnb/) is recommended [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/import-jupyter-notebook-script-into-a-python-script/11747/2?u=fomightez) for making importing notebooks more convenient. Or, I just came across the [subnotebook](https://github.com/davidbrochart/subnotebook) project that let's you run a notebook as you would call a Python function, pass parameters and get results back, including output contents.