# Is there a way to run all Jupyter Notebooks inside a directory?

Tags: python, automation, jupyter-notebook

## Introduction

I have a lot of Jupyter Notebooks inside a directory and I want to run them all to see them output.

## What I actually do

I have to **open them each one**, click on *"Restart kernel and re-run the whole notebook?"*, wait a few minutes and then go for the next one.

## What I wish to do

Find a way to just "press a button" (it can be a **script, command, or everything**), go away for a walk, and come back reading what's the output.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `nbconvert` or `papermill`.
See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078735/start-notebook-from-other-notebook).

This is an example in `papermill`:

Installation with Anaconda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge papermill
```

Create a new notebook that runs all the notebooks in a specific directory:

```
import papermill as pm
from pathlib import Path

for nb in Path('./run_all').glob('*.ipynb'):
    pm.execute_notebook(
        input_path=nb,
        output_path=nb  # Path to save executed notebook
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

[papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill) and [nbclient](https://github.com/jupyter/nbclient) have an overhead since they create a new process to execute the code; plus, they cannot execute notebooks in parallel.

I ran some benchmarks, and I'm showing a few options from the fastest to the slowest one (I used [these notebooks](https://github.com/h3abionet/african_microbiome_portal_data/tree/main/Notebooks) for benchmarking), and I used the `time` command to time the execution.

## Fastest: [Ploomber](https://github.com/ploomber/ploomber) in parallel

```
25.440 total
```

```py
from ploomber import DAG
from ploomber.products import File
from ploomber.tasks import NotebookRunner
from ploomber.executors import Parallel

from pathlib import Path
from glob import iglob

dag = DAG(executor=Parallel())


for path in iglob('*.ipynb'):
    NotebookRunner(Path(path), File(path), dag=dag, papermill_params=dict(engine_name='embedded'))


if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    dag.build(force=True)
```

This requires:

```bash
pip install ploomber
```

## Papermill using [ploomber-engine](https://github.com/ploomber/ploomber-engine)

```
51.256 total
```

```py
import papermill as pm
from glob import glob

for nb in glob('*.ipynb'):
    pm.execute_notebook(
        input_path=nb,
        output_path=nb,
        engine_name='embedded',
    )
```

This requires:

```bash
pip install ploomber-engine
```

## Ploomber (serial)

```bash
59.324 total
```

```py
from ploomber import DAG
from ploomber.products import File
from ploomber.tasks import NotebookRunner
from ploomber.executors import Parallel

from pathlib import Path
from glob import iglob

dag = DAG()


for path in iglob('*.ipynb'):
    NotebookRunner(Path(path), File(path), dag=dag, papermill_params=dict(engine_name='embedded'))


if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    dag.build(force=True)
```

This requires:

```bash
pip install ploomber
```

## Slowest: papermill

```
1:58.79 total
```

```py
import papermill as pm
from glob import glob

for nb in glob('*.ipynb'):
    pm.execute_notebook(
        input_path=nb,
        output_path=nb,
    )
```

This requires:

```bash
pip install papermill
```

*Note:* I did not evaluate `nbclient` since the performance is similar to `papermill`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert every single notebook that you want to run in a `.py` file and then create a single notebook that imports them as modules. Something like this:

script1.py:

```
print('This is the first script.')
```

script2.py:

```
print('This is the second script.')
```

script3.py:

```
print('...and this is the last one!')
```

Now you import them all in a single script (you can create it in Jupyter):

```
import script1
import script2
import script3
# This is the first script.
# This is the second script.
# ...and this is the last one!
```