# Can you run a juptyer notebook file from another python file?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I currently have a data link and a jupyter notebook file. I am trying to write a python script that grabs the data from the link, and then prompts it to run the jupyter notebook.

So the question is are you able to run a jupyter notebook (.ipynb) file from inside a python (.py) file?

Comment: it is not your answer but as a suggestion, you can download your Jupyter codes as `.py` then use it as a python script file.

Comment: There is also JupyText (and probably similar other addons) that will automatically generate `.py` files from Jupyter as the notebook is saved. Running a python file from a python file, I would imagine, is much more simple then trying to run a jupyter notebook from a python file. I've never tried either though.

Comment: downloading it as a python file, and running that in the other code seems to be the easiest option. Thanks!

Comment: If for development purposes you absolutely don't want two versions of the code and you cannot use Jupytext to keep the two versions sync'd, you can use the commands/tools `jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute`, `jupytext --execute`, or `papermill` from inside your Python script to execute a notebook file directly. Usually in the Python script you can get away with using such commands in `os.system(<command_here>)` and not need subprocess. Third paragraph of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60081404/8508004) links to the details on the commands, except for the Jupytext command.